# Unable to reference Jinja 2 variable inside a function

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

So i have a slight bit of an issue with jinja variable reference within a function.

I've tried a handful of different methods to make this work, but none of them have yield any results. I hope some of you can help me out here!

```
{% set device_type = salt['grains.get']('device','') %}
{% set ip_addr = salt['network.ip_addrs'](' +device_type+ ')[0] %}
```

I'd like to have the variable device_type inside the salt function within ip_addr.

I have tried the following already and none of it gave any results:

```
{% set ip_addr = salt['network.ip_addrs'](\' +device_type+ \')[0] %}
{% set ip_addr = salt['network.ip_addrs'](' ~ device_type ~ ')[0] %}
{% set ip_addr = salt['network.ip_addrs']( {{ device_type }})[0] %}
{% set ip_addr = salt['network.ip_addrs'](' {{ device_type }} ')[0] %}
```

Does anyone know how I could replace the device_type within that function?

Comment: Can you explain more here, like put plainly what is your purpose using plain python code, to understand which variable you want to which function and what are these `['network.ip_addrs']` and  `[0]` for ?

Comment: It takes the device first ip address in the list. Which is in this case the machines address and then it gets distributed among configuration file.

Comment: Issue is that i'm unable to refer the device_type parameter inside the set function

Comment: so `salt['network.ip_addrs']` is a function that you want to pass `device_type` as parameter?

Comment: Yes. I had some weird errors before, but the solution below worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was as easy as

```
{% set ip_addr = salt['network.ip_addrs']( device_type )[0] %}
```

Without anything supernatural.